# Copyright status of a letter on U.S. Senator's letterhead

Tags: copyright

Under [17 USC 105](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/105), there is no copyright protection for a "work of the United States Government," which [17 USC 101](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/101) defines as "a work prepared by an officer or employee of the United States Government as part of that person’s official duties."

What would be the copyright status of a letter written to a private individual by a U.S. senator on official letterhead? Assume that the subject matter is not any official act of government, but falls under the category of constituent relationship building and getting re-elected.

I'm guessing the senator would hold copyright, but I wonder if anyone knows for sure.

Comment: Constituent relations are an official duty of elected legislators.  Was the letter sent using the franking privilege?

Comment: @phoog Good question -- the particular letter in question is an archival holding from decades ago where the envelope didn't survive, so it's hard to say. I'm guessing, however, that senators don't personally buy rolls of stamps for letters they have their assistants type up and send. So the probability would be that the franking privilege was used.

Comment: As far as I understand it the franking privilege is for official business only, but if the envelope didn't survive that's not going to be very helpful.

Comment: Interesting article on franking: https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/minute/Senate_Ends_Franked_Mail_Priviledge.htm#:~:text=January%2022%2C%201873,it%20into%20law%20in%201789.

Comment: Maybe senators don't buy lots of postage, but there was a well known case of a congressman (actually mine at the time) buying a LOT of postage: [ROSTENKOWSKI INDICTED ON CHARGES HE DEFRAUDED THE U.S. OF $500,000](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1994/06/01/rostenkowski-indicted-on-charges-he-defrauded-the-us-of-500000/f1af38e7-860d-40ec-9acb-df80b9d89ca0/)

Answer (score 4):

The Copyright Office has determined, in [chapter 300](https://www.copyright.gov/comp3/chap300/ch300-copyrightable-authorship.pdf) of the *Compendium of U.S. Copyright Office Practices,* on page 36, that the copyright bar extends to

> works created by the President; **Congress;** the federal judiciary;
> federal departments, agencies, boards, bureaus, or commissions; or any other officer or employee of the U.S. federal government while acting within the course of his or her official duties.

So the Senator is a US employee for copyright purposes, at least according to the US Copyright Office. Technically, this is interpretation rather than law, and in theory a court might disagree, but if anyone is qualified to speak on this issue, it's the Copyright Office. In my opinion, it is most reasonable to assume that the Copyright Office is correct in their interpretation unless there is case law directly contradicting them.

The only question is whether the letter was created by the Senator "while acting within the course of his or her official duties." I'm not aware of any case law suggesting that constituent building is or is not an "official duty" of a US Senator, and there are reasonable arguments to be made in both directions. On the one hand, the letter is clearly beyond the scope of Congress's lawmaking and oversight Constitutional functions. On the other, the office of Senator is an inherently political office, and a case can be made that campaigning for reelection is part of the job. Perhaps surprisingly, *that* question was extensively litigated during E. Jean Carroll's first defamation lawsuit against Donald Trump, because Trump argued that his statements about Carroll were within the scope of his employment (and so a defamation claim would be effectively barred under the Westfall Act). To my understanding, the current disposition of that lawsuit is that this is considered a question of fact for a jury to decide (at least [according to the Second Circuit](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/23785422-carrollca2opn042123)).

What can be said is who does *not* hold copyright: The US Senate and/or the US government as a whole. The only way the Senate could acquire copyright in this letter (short of the Senator directly granting it to them) would be as a work made for hire, but the work-for-hire doctrine requires that the work be prepared by an employee as part of their official duties, just like the federal copyright bar. So the Senate cannot acquire copyright in this manner. If anyone owns the copyright, it is most likely the Senator.

Comment: Query whether a work created by a member of Congress is a "work created by Congress." I would have thought that refers to congressional reports and other documents issued under the apparent authority of the legislature itself, as opposed to one (potentially dissenting) member.

Comment: @sjy: That goes to the "within the course of his or her official duties" issue, not the "are they an employee of the US" issue. If they're not an employee of the US, then *none* of their works would *ever* become public domain, including (for example) a law written entirely by one lawmaker with no help from aides (which would be unusual, but not entirely unheard of).

Comment: The law cannot be copyrighted because it is a [government edict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edict_of_government). I'm not sure I understand your point about works not becoming public domain, but I think Dale M's answer is broadly correct – a member of Congress is not "an officer or employee of the United States Government" as defined in 17 USC 101. That seems inconsistent with the [Ineligibility Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ineligibility_Clause). The relationship between a member of Congress and the United States Government is *sui generis*.

Comment: @sjy: The Supreme Court's discussion of the government edicts doctrine in [*Georgia v. PRO*](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/19pdf/18-1150_7m58.pdf) tends to suggest that the government edicts doctrine is "much narrower" than the federal officials doctrine ("...That rule, however, applies to all federal officials, regardless of
the nature and scope of their duties. It does not suggest an intent to
displace the much narrower government edits doctrine with respect to
the States."). It does not make sense to read the edicts doctrine as covering things not covered by the federal bar.

Answer (score -2):

### The Senator owns the copyright

There is no [copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_status_of_works_by_the_federal_government_of_the_United_States) in "a work prepared by an officer or employee of the United States Government as part of that person's official duties."

An [officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Officer_of_the_United_States) is a functionary of the executive or judicial branches, and an employee is someone engaged under an employment contract. As an elected representative in the legislative branch, a congressperson is neither (even though the US Government pays them).

They are not an officer because of how that term is defined. They are not an employee because their role is defined by law and not by contract - the US Government does not tell them how to do their job, when to do their job, where to do their job, and, most importantly, can’t fire them; merely paying them is not enough to create an employment relationship. As such, they own the copyright in what they do.

[Congressional staffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congressional_staff) are either employees of the Congress and, therefore US government employees, or employees of individual Congresspersons and, therefore, not employees of the US Government. The former “run” the Congress and since a subset of them prepare the offical publications of Congress (minutes, bills etc) those works are exempt from copyright. The latter, which likely included the actual person who wrote the OP’s letter, aren’t employees of the US Government and what they write is covered by copyright which, by virtue of their employment relationship with a particular Congressperson, vests in their employer.

Comment: First and foremost, Senators are not part of the judicial branch, they are in the legislative branch.  Neither are they a congressperson.  And they are absolutely employees of the US Government.  Second, if "constituent relationship building and getting re-elected", is not part of their official duties, then it probably shouldn't be written on letterhead.  It's either private correspondence, or government business.  I'm not clear on the right answer, but this isn't it...

Comment: @MichaelHall I don't know enough to comment about the rest of your statement, but Representatives (House) and Senators (Senate) are _both_ Congresspersons (members of Congress).

Comment: @BenHocking, I understand that there are two houses, and you can consider my second sentence amended or deleted.  My point is that in common parlance Senators generally are NOT referred to as Congresspersons.  https://borgenproject.org/difference-between-a-congressman-and-a-senator/

Comment: @MichaelHall Congresspeople are not officers of the US because of the definition of that term. They are not employees because the US Government has no control over how they do their jobs, acannot hire or fire them, etc.

Comment: DaleM, the term "officer of the United States" does not have the same definition in every context.  @MichaelHall DaleM is right, however, that members of Congress are certainly not employees of the United States.  They are elected officers; they hold an office.

Comment: @phoog, Are they employed?  Are they paid wages?  "Holding an office" is just puffed up important sounding words - they work for the people.

Comment: @MichaelHall Being paid does not you an employee. Company directors (non-executive) are paid but they are not legally employees

Comment: Again, I would assert that they are employees of the people, (or employees of the stockholders) but that's a philosophical and linguistic distinction vs a legal one.  Let's just leave it at that...